# How to manage different column for save data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

I am new in codeigniter4 and i am trying to save "formdata",Here is my controller code

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('signup');
    }

    public function store() {
        $userModel = new UserModel();
        $data = [
            'first_name' => $this->request->getVar('fname'),
            'last_name'  => $this->request->getVar('lname'),
        ];
        $userModel->insert($data);
        return $this->response->redirect(site_url('/users-list'));
    }
}
```

Here is my model file

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;
class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sign';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
}
```

Data is submitting into database successfully but i have few question regarding this

1. If we want to use other function(additional_data) for "save data into database"(age,address) then how we do this ?
2. How can we handle different "$table" , "$allowedFields"  in same model file ?

Answer (score 0):

To use two different tables and fields in the same model.

**here is a syntax**

```
class My_model extends CI_Model {

    private $table1 = 'table1';
    private $table1_fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');

    private $table2 = 'table2';
    private $table2_fields = array('field4', 'field5', 'field6');
    
    // rest of the model code
}
```

Your code should be

```
class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sign';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
    
    protected $table = 'address_table';
    protected $allowedFields = ['age', 'age'];
}
```

Add a model function to switch the table based on usage

```
public function get_allowed_fields($table) {
    switch($table) {
        case $this->table1:
            return $this->table1_fields;
            break;
        case $this->table2:
            return $this->table2_fields;
            break;
        default:
            return array();
            break;
    }
}
```

and here is your controller code for getting data based on the selected table.

```
$allowed_fields = $this->get_allowed_fields($this->table1);
$this->db->select($allowed_fields);
$query = $this->db->get($this->table1);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: and what about controller ? means how controller can handle this ? kindly post controller function/code also

Comment: and how controller know that which table should be use in model file ?

Comment: for this, you should improve your code and add your logic. and getting any issue we are here for help.

Comment: means we should use "switch" for handle different functions (i.e add or edit or delete) , am i right ?

Comment: yes, or create functions for different usages. like `add(), edit(), delete()`

Comment: "Create functions" in controller , am i right ?

Comment: no, into the model.